# Installation Error (Openni Driver)

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the instruction steps on http://ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect with:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect

hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers openni-drivers
cd openni-drivers
make
sudo make install
```

All instructions works fine till then "sudo make install" I get an error which looks like this:

```
sudo make install
cd openni && make
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/user/ros_workspace/openni-drivers/openni'
cd build/openni/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist && bash RedistMaker && cd -


*********************************
*   PrimeSense OpenNI Redist    *
*     2012-04-03 17:45:18       *
*********************************

Target: Linux-x86
Version: 1.5.2.23
Num of compile jobs: 2

* Building OpenNI...
../../../../../Source/Utils/niLicense/niLicense.cpp: In Funktion »int main(int, char**)«:
../../../../../Source/Utils/niLicense/niLicense.cpp:122:108: Warnung: Format »%lu« erwartet Argumenttyp »long unsigned int«, aber Argument 2 hat Typ »unsigned int« [-Wformat]
../../../../../Source/Utils/niLicense/niLicense.cpp:129:97: Warnung: Format »%lu« erwartet Argumenttyp »long unsigned int«, aber Argument 2 hat Typ »unsigned int« [-Wformat]
* Creating Doxygen...
warning: ignoring unsupported tag `INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  =' at line 304, file Doxyfile
warning: ignoring unsupported tag `CITE_BIB_FILES         =' at line 579, file Doxyfile
warning: ignoring unsupported tag `MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     =' at line 1202, file Doxyfile
warning: ignoring unsupported tag `LATEX_BIB_STYLE        =' at line 1321, file Doxyfile
warning: ignoring unsupported tag `INTERACTIVE_SVG        =' at line 1734, file Doxyfile
When enabling GENERATE_HTMLHELP the tree view (GENERATE_TREEVIEW) should be disabled. I'll do it for you.
sh: C:\Program Files\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe: not found
error: failed to run html help compiler on index.hhp
* Creating Redist Dir...
* Copying files to redist dir...
Samples: ['NiRecordSynthetic', 'NiSimpleSkeleton', 'NiSampleModule', 'NiCRead', 'NiUserSelection', 'NiSimpleCreate', 'NiAudioSample', 'NiSimpleViewer', 'NiHandTracker', 'NiSimpleRead', 'NiConvertXToONI', 'SimpleViewer.java', 'NiUserTracker', 'SimpleRead.java', 'UserTracker.java', 'NiViewer', 'NiBackRecorder']
* Removing Read Only Attributes...
* Fixing Files...
* Creating Makefile...
* Copying install script...
* Building Samples in release configuration......
* Building Samples in debug configuration......
* Creating tar......
* Redist OpenNi Ended.   !!
/home/user/ros_workspace/openni-drivers/openni
touch installed
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/jerome/ros_workspace/openni-drivers/openni'
sudo mkdir -p /usr/include/openni \
                                /etc/openni \
                                /usr/share/openni/doc \
                                /usr/share/openni/samples \
                                /usr/lib/pkgconfig
sudo cp -f ./openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/Redist/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.2.23/Samples/Config/* /etc/openni/
sudo cp -f ./openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/Redist/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.2.23/Lib/*.so /usr/lib/
sudo cp -r ./openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/Redist/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.2.23/Include/* /usr/include/openni/
sudo cp -f ./openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/Redist/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.2.23/Bin/* /usr/bin/
sudo cp -f ./openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/Redist/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.2.23/Documentation/html/* /usr/share/openni/doc/
sudo cp -f ./openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/Redist/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.2.23/Samples/Bin/x86-Release/Sample-* /usr/share/openni/samples/
sudo cp -f ./openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/Redist/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.2.23/Samples/Bin/x86-Release/NiViewer /usr/share/openni/samples/
sudo sed s/__VERSION__/1.5.2.23~oneiric/ ./CONTROL/openni.pc > /usr/lib/pkgconfig/openni-dev.pc


sudo /bin/bash ./CONTROL/openni_postinst configure
./CONTROL/openni_postinst: Zeile 21: 21984 Ungültiger Maschinenbefehl   /usr/bin/niReg -r /usr/lib/libnimCodecs.so /etc/openni
make: *** [install_openni] ERROR 132

user@userPC:~/ros_workspace/openni-drivers$
```

This error occurs in the makefile-directory (~/openni-drivers/CONTROL/openni_postinst):

```
...
  /usr/bin/niReg -r /usr/lib/libnimCodecs.so /etc/openni
  /usr/bin/niReg -r /usr/lib/libnimMockNodes.so /etc/openni
  /usr/bin/niReg -r /usr/lib/libnimRecorder.so /etc/openni
...
```

It's a basic installation error, but I dont know where to look at to solve this instruction error.

Or could I comment this line of codes?

Best regards from Germany

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31091/installation-error-(openni-driver)/) by [GermanUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2107/germanuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GermanUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2107/germanuser/) on 2012-04-03**:
This error already exists here but there was no answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/12174/problem-installing-openni-on-ubuntu-1004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Once you've done the first step (`sudo apt-get instal...`), you're done. If you've installed the binaries, you don't need to install it from source.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2